# Namespace 'google.maps.places' has no exported member 'AutocompleteService'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have spent hour on this I have no clue what else to try or to read to find out what is the problem.

I have included google api library into project

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

and installed typings

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

Now in my service I want to use class from googlemap lib:

```
type AutocompletePrediction = google.maps.places.AutocompleteService.AutocompletePrediction;
```

typescript underlines `AutocompleteService` with red color and says that:

```
Namespace 'google.maps.places' has no exported member 'AutocompleteService'.
```

but actually when I check google typings definitions I can clearly see it there.

[image]

This is how error looks like
[image]

Autocomplete/suggestions work well
[image]
[image]

Where can be the problem?
Any hints appreciated, thanks :)

I am on Mac OS 10.14.6 Mojave, and using VScode version: 1.41.1

PS: I cannot just ignore it, because my pipeline breaks on same errors :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `type AutocompletePrediction = google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction`?

`AutocompleteService` is a class, and that class does not have a `AutocompletePrediction` member. The error message is confusing likely because TS sees by the access to `AutocompleteService.AutocompletePrediction` and thinks that `AutocompleteService` should be a namespace